# How to exclude a blank page in lyx?

Tags: formatting, lyx, pagestyle

I am writing a document in lyx. The document's first page must be a pdf page that I imported (I did not writed anything, just imported the document). However, when I run to pdf format, it starts with a blank page first, and the second page is the document that I imported. How should I start my document to exclude this first blank page in lyx?

Comment: your import method is wrong, it produce a too large graphic and so latex pushes it to the next page. You need to use pdfpages (but I have no idea how to do it in lyx).

Comment: I used the option import external files -->pdfpages, as you said. However, it did not work

Comment: You can insert the PFD just as any image: `Insert` → `Graphics`  but is up to you set the appropriate size. Note that any  image is placed as a big character, so if you type a huge "A" (e.g.: with DejaVu Sans font using XeteX, type `\fontsize{800}{800}\selectfont A` in a ERT box) it  will also leave a blank page before to appearin the second page (but partly and invading right margin, because it cannot be fitted anyway).